# Send the push notification FCM (Firebase cloud messagging) to the current user

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application with `kotlin` and I want to send notifications to only one user when Status data is change. 
First, I try Topics with postman but that is not what am looking for !
So, am looking for a solution that makes me send push notification to the only user who has status changes.

Someone please tell me how to do that.

Comment: please share code what you have tried in android.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far. Have you tried sending push notification using push registration id?

Comment: No .. so how can i use this registration id ?

Comment: Here is an official example with Cloud Functions https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/fcm-notifications

Comment: i tried this tutorial : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple?authuser=0

Comment: thanks @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 0):

Every device get tokens when registers in your app. You can get this tokens and save in database. Eventually, You can take from this database and send messages as you said to particular users.

Comment: This might go as a comment. Not an answer I suppose. If you are putting an answer, please provide some code and the data structure of the database along with the tutorial that supports the answer.

Comment: @Rasulbek Abdurasulov how can i find the genereted tokens !?

Comment: @Taysirboubaker There is no central registry of such tokens. But even if there was, the tokens in FCM are not associated with a user (since each user can have multiple devices, and each device can have multiple users). If you need a registry of "device token(s) for a user" you will have to create that yourself. The sample that Renaud linked to does that, and my tutorial here shows another way to target users: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thnx for your help ..your tutorial can help me to get the idea  but about the tokens isn't genereted or shown in log , so i can use it right ?